# How to implement the moderation of new posts at Django 2.1

Tags: python, django

I'm beginner in Django. I'm write on Django 2.1, Python 3.6. Faced the following problem.
I want to moderate new posts created. That is, that it was possible to put a tick in the admin panel, and only after that the post would be published.
But ideally, of course, so that the administrator could see the new entries right on the site and allow them to publish right there.

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    moderation = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(required=True)
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'body']
```

**views.py**

```
from .forms import PostForm

class PostCreateView(FormView):
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'blog/post_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(PostCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return response
```

**admin.py**

```
from .models import Post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'user', 'moderation')

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^posts/$', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='posts'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
]
```

I want it to be like in the picture. Or you can watch and moderate the post right away on the site.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAubL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in your PostListView, define the get_queryset method like this:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
   ...

   def get_queryset(self):
      queryset = super(PostListView, self).get_queryset()
      return queryset.filter(moderation=True)
```

What happens here is that, unless the posts are moderated by admin, it will be available in PostListView. More details on filter is available in this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter).

Comment: Very thanks. It is i wanted and.
Do not tell me how to make this opportunity for admins? _As example [scrin1](https://i.imgur.com/vkN9diO.png) [scrin2](https://i.imgur.com/0ZNx7z9.png)_

Comment: You can add `moderation` to [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) in ModelAdmin.

Comment: You did not understand. I want to show a new post, which has not yet been published, in the template "post_list.html" for the administrator (staff), for example "scrin1" in the previous comment. This is to ensure that they (each employee) are not logged in to the admin panel of the site, but allowed to publish this message from the site page (template "post_detail"). I tried to do it with __staff_member_required__ in py views, but it didn't work out. Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow. Maybe I should post a new Ask with the code "post_list.html" and "post_detail.html"?

Comment: that would be great. :)

Comment: Good. Here it is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54147299/how-display-post-on-moderation-for-admin-at-site-page-post-list-at-django-2