# How display post "on moderation" for admin at site page "Post list" at Django 2.1?

Tags: python, django

[Previous Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139063/how-to-implement-the-moderation-of-new-posts-at-django-2-1)

I want to display a new post, which exist "on moderation",  for the administrator (staff), at site page "Post list" (template "post_list.html"), for example "scrin1" (Post 1 - published; Post 2 - "on moderation"). Regular user can see "Post list" only with published posts, see "scrin2". This to ensure that each admin didn't enter in to the admin panel of the site, but can published this post from the site page "Post update" (template "post_form.html"), for example "scrin3".
I tried to do it with staff_member_required in views.py (form_valid in PostListView), but it didn't work out.
If post was edited, must go moderation too before publish edited version.

The following code shows the implementation of moderation of posts from the admin panel. I just don’t know how to make the moderation of posts (created or updated) from the site page (without logging in to the admin panel, for example, from the site page "... / post /  / update", simply by ticking the checkbox in "Moderation")

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    moderation = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(required=True)
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'body']
```

**views.py**

```
from .forms import PostForm

class PostListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(PostListView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(moderation=True)


class PostCreateView(FormView):
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'blog/post_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(PostCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return response


class PostUpdateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'body']
    permission_required = 'blog.can_mark_returned'
```

**admin.py**

```
from .models import Post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'user', 'moderation')

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^posts/$', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='posts'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    url(r'^post/create/$', views.PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post_create'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$', views.PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_update'),
]
```

**post_list.html**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}    
{% block title %}<title>Posts list</title>{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>All posts</h1>
    {% if post_list %}
        <ul>
        {% for post in post_list %}
            <li><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a> {{ post.user }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
    <p>There are no posts.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**post_form.html**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**Screen1** view page "Posts list" as "Admin"

[image: screen1 view page "Posts list" as "Admin"]

**Screen2** view page "Posts list" as "Regular user"

[image: screen2 view page "Posts list" as "Regular user"]

**Screen3** view page "Post update" as "Admin" with "Moderation" checkbox

[image: screen3 view page "Post update" as "Admin" with "Moderation" checkbox]

Comment: Can you be more specific than 'it doesn't work'? What doesn't work? Is there an error? Is something being shown that shouldn't be shown? It's good you're showing all the code, and you explain the behaviour you want to see, but you need to describe better the actual problem. e.g. "when user who isn't admin does X then Y happens but it should be Z." or "when admin user clicks on X this error Y is shown"

Comment: There is no error. I just want to fasten the possibility _for admins to moderate_ entries directly on the site - _without logging in to the admin panel_.

Comment: Ok but what exactly isn’t working?

Comment: There are no errors in the code. The code shows the implementation of moderation of posts from the admin panel. I just don’t know how to make the moderation of posts (created or updated) from the site page (without logging in to the admin panel, for example, from the site page "... / post / <id> / update", simply by ticking the checkbox in "Moderation")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can update your view as below, if i really understand your problem.

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}    
{% block title %}<title>Posts list</title>{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>All posts</h1>
    {% if post_list %}
        <ul>
        {% for post in post_list %}
            <li><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a> {{ post.user }}</li> 
            {% if post.moderation and request.user.is_staff %} 
                <form action="{% url 'moderator-approval' post.pk %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit">Approve</button>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>There are no posts.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

In your `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [ 
     path('moderator-approval/<int:post_id>/', views.moderator_approval_view, name="moderator-approval")
]
```

In yours `views.py`

```
def moderator_approval_view(request, **kwargs):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=kwargs['post_id'])
        post.moderation = True
        post.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('posts')
```

Comment: Close to the truth.

But there is few errors:
1. In order for a post to appear in the "Posts list" page, need to go to the admin panel anyway and tick "Moderation". This is due to the "Moderation" settings in Post (models.py) and get_query_set PostListView (views.py). Okay, let's leave it as it is. I make a moderation in the admin panel.

Comment: 2. After moderation, in the admin panel on the "Posts List" page, under the entry appears the "Approve" button (if see as admin). When click on it, a KeyError at /blog/ moderator-approval/16  'post_id' error occurs. If look at this page as a normal user or guest, all entries are visible..

As I understand it, there should be the following.
1.On the "Posts list" page, when viewing from the administrator, all (old, new and updated) posts should be displayed. Under the new and updated posts should be the "Approve" button, when clicked, the posts are published. Without enter to the admin panel.

Comment: 2. On the "Posts list" page, when viewing from a regular user or guest, only old published posts should be displayed.

Comment: I just didn't understand what you are trying to say and do.