# How add link to profile? Django 2.1.5

Tags: python, django

I have url, but it work with error.
For example, link must be example/profile/3, but template redirects to example/profile/4. 
Profile create with signals. I watch, id user and id profile not matching.Maybe, error in this. Template redirects to link with id "User", but not id "Profile"!
Pls help me.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='')
    #other fields

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    #other fields    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**signals.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**admin.py**

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'location', 'about_me', 'contacts')

admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

**views.py**

```
class PostCreateView(FormView):
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'post/post_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(PostCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return response

class PostDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
```

current **urls.py**

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='profile-detail'),
```

**post_detail.html**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}
<p><strong>Author:</strong> <a href="{% url 'profile-detail' post.user.pk %}">{{ post.user }}</a></p>
<p><strong>Description:</strong></p>
<p>{{ post.body|safe }}</p>
...
```

Comment: "id user and id profile not matching" - You should not rely on the fact that they will be the same.

Comment: @FUNNYDMAN I'm understand this. How fix the template redirect to id Profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are few changes you need do, like:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

You don't need this signal. As User and Profile is connected by OneToOne already, and they are separate instances. If you update `user`, you don't need to update `profile` as well.

Also, the issue with your question is that you are redirected to wrong profile. I think the problem is you are passing wrong Primary Key via url here. You are looking for profile but you are passing user id. So you need to change like this:

```
<p><strong>Author:</strong> <a href="{% url 'profile-detail' post.user.profile.pk %}">{{ post.user }}</a></p>
```

You should be able to access `profile` from `user.profile`. For more details please check [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) regarding **OneToOne** field.

Comment: Thnx. It is so simple, it turns out)

Comment: Could you help this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54147299/how-display-post-on-moderation-for-admin-at-site-page-post-list-at-django-2